# celery, postgresql -> configure backend

Tags: python, celery, backend

So i'm just getting started with celery and trying to do some simple tests to get a feel for it.
Im trying to set a celery to use postgres for my backend.
on this page:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results
I see the example

```
celery = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='amqp://')
```

So in my code I try

```
celery = Celery('tasks', 
               backend='sqla+postgresql://celery_exp:celery_exp@myhost/celery_exp',
                broker='sqla+postgresql://celery_exp:celery_exp@myhost/celery_exp',)
```

but i keep getting this error when starting it:

```
ImportError: No module named sqla+postgresql
```

In the docs I've tried different variations such as

```
postgresql://  
postgresql+psycopg2://
```

I know that the connection string is correct besause taking out the backend paramter in the Celery constructor works as expected.
What am i doing wrong here? I feel it must be something stupid because I can't find anything on the net.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

The answer lies here [http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#database-url-examples](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-backend-settings)

You need to prefix your regular SQL Alchemy url string with `db+`, such as

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "db+postgresql+psycopg2://..."
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  My particular flavor of error was `"'module' object is not callable"`, which was not terribly helpful in tracking this down.

Comment: Here's a feature request I added to celery to make these types of errors easier to debug: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2945

Comment: Note that if you use a DB result backend, you also need to install relevant libraries. For example, I use postgresql, so I need: pip install SQLAlchemy, pip install psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

Celery takes the URL you pass it, looks at the prefix (in this case "sqla+postgresql") and looks for a backend that matches that. There is no "generic" load a backend with just the database alone. You can check the backend/**init**.py in your celery folder on your system to see the entire alias dictionary, and then add your own.